# How to Generate .RBI file for an ActiveModel Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorbet

I have a PORO that I'm using as a value object. I'm adding ActiveModel via `include ActiveModel::Model` for all of the niceties that that brings me. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to generate RBI files for it so that it will pass `srb tc`

I'm currently using `sorbet-rails` and since this is a PORO and does not inherit from `ActiveRecord`, `bundle exec rails_rbi:all` or `bundle exec rails_rbi:models` will not generate .rbi files for this even if I place it in the models dir (which it should not live in).

I *could* write the .rbi files by hand, but I really don't want to do that. Is there a way that I can auto generate them?

Here is a parred down example of the module I need an RBI file for

```rb
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    include ActiveModel::Model
    extend T::Sig

    VALID_VARIANTS = T.let(['Enum1', 'Enum2'], T::Array[String])

    sig { returns(String) }
    attr_accessor :variant

    validates :variant, presence: true, inclusion: { in: VALID_VARIANTS }
    validate :enum_1_is_valid, if: Proc.new { |a| a.variant == 'Enum1' }

    private

    sig { void }
    def enum_1_is_valid
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is causing a problem for you? The above code looks perfectly fine to me, except for the definition of methods coming from `ActiveModel::Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `sorbet-typed` does not include `ActiveModel::Model` which is just a wrapper around `ActiveModel::Validations` and a few others. By switching to only using `ActiveModel::Validations`, the code now passes `typed: strict`.

The main downside to this is we don't get the nice automatic attribute assignment and still need to use an initializer. Not a big deal, but not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to typing ActiveModels is as follows.

I created a base class called `ApplicationModel`.

```
class ApplicationModel
  extend T::Sig
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
end

class ExampleModel < ApplicationModel
  attribute :name, :string
end
```

I then have a script that generates RBI files for subclasses of `ApplicationModel`.

```
ApplicationModel.subclasses.each do |model|
  # Generate RBI files.
end
```

Take a look at how [tapioca generates RBI files for ActiveRecord objects](https://github.com/Shopify/tapioca/blob/4dd74c8110ac8a2b530f4b9b9eea03439f6660b1/lib/tapioca/compilers/dsl/active_record_columns.rb#L307) for how to generate type signatures.